# How to wrap an abstract class hierarchy in Java

Tags: java, wrapper

I am writing a library (wrapperLibrary) that wrappers all classes of another library (dependentLibrary) and I want to enforce integrators to use only the classes from wrapperLibrary and **NOT** from dependentLibrary - wrapping it throughly.

I am trying to find a way to wrap the below Abstract hierarchy of dependentLibrary:

```
public abstract class AOT{
    // Has few abstract methods and few default method implementation
}

public abstract class AMOT extends AOT {
    // Has a new abstract method and few overridden methods
}

public class COTM extends AMOT{
    // Implementation class of the abstract hierarchy
}
```

The wrapper should look like:

```
public abstract class AOTWrapper{
    // Has the default method implementation of AOT
}

public abstract class AMOTWrapper extends AOTWrapper {
    // Has the default method implementation of AMOT
}

public class COTMWrapper extends AMOTWrapper{
    // Implementation class of the abstract hierarchy
}
```

The integrators or consumers of wrapperLibrary shouldn't have access to AOT / AMOT / COTM.

Also other classes in dependentLibrary have AOT / AMOT / COTM as method parameters or return types. So, we should be able to covert AOTWrapper to AOT as and when needed.

How could we achieve this?

Comment: What Java are you using? Until Java 1.9 there is no way to keep public Java classes inside your code, but prevent users from having access to them.

Answer (score 0):

This would not be actually a wrapper which commonly known as a particular design pattern. It requires that wrapper and wrapped classes are implementing the same interface, but you actually can extend the last child concrete class of the lib by the abstract parent of all wrappers and override all related methods, you realize that in this case all wrappers will inherit all libs methods, but you can override unnecessary with exception throwing(similar kind of trick you can find in some methods of java.util.AbstractList, for example). Then, probably good solution would be to use a factory which will properly create your lib instance, put to wrapper and provide to the customer in any class container he would prefer. Would be something like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WrapperFactory wrapperFactory = new WrapperFactory();
        COTMWrapper cotmWrapper = wrapperFactory.getWrapper(COTMWrapper.class);
        cotmWrapper.doCOTMStuff();
        cotmWrapper.doSomethingElse();
        AMOTWrapper amotWrapper = cotmWrapper;
        amotWrapper.doAOTStuff();
        AOTWrapper aotWrapper = amotWrapper;
        aotWrapper.doAOTStuff();
        AOT likeNotWrapped = cotmWrapper;
        likeNotWrapped.doSomething();
    }

}
 class WrapperFactory {

    public <T extends AOTWrapper> T  getWrapper(Class<T> type){
        COTM cotm = new COTM();
        return type.cast(new COTMWrapper(cotm));
    }
}

abstract class AOT {
    // Has few abstract methods and few default method implementation
    public abstract void doSomething();

    public void doAOTStuff() {
        // AOT stuff is doing
    }

}

abstract class AMOT extends AOT {
    // Has a new abstract method and few overridden methods
    public abstract void doSomethingElse();

    public void doSomething() {
        // AMOT stuff is doing
    }

}

class COTM extends AMOT {
    // Implementation class of the abstract hierarchy

    public void doSomethingElse() {
        doCOTMStuff();
    }

    public void doCOTMStuff() {
        // COTM stuff is doing
    }
}

abstract class AOTWrapper extends COTM {

    private AOT container;

    public AOTWrapper(AOT container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    @Override
    public void doAOTStuff() {
        container.doAOTStuff();
    }

     @Override
    public void doCOTMStuff() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomethingElse() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    // Has the default method implementation of AOT
}

abstract class AMOTWrapper extends AOTWrapper {

    private AMOT container;

    public AMOTWrapper(AMOT container) {
        super(container);
        this.container = container;
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        container.doSomething();
    }

    // Has the default method implementation of AMOT
}

class COTMWrapper extends AMOTWrapper {

    private COTM container;

    public COTMWrapper(COTM container) {
        super(container);
        this.container = container;
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomethingElse() {
        container.doSomethingElse();
    }

    @Override
    public void doCOTMStuff() {
        container.doCOTMStuff();
        // COTM stuff is doing
    }
//     Implementation class of the abstract hierarchy
}
```

Another approach:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        COTMWrapper cotmWrapper = new COTMWrapper();
        AMOTInter amotWrapper = cotmWrapper;
        amotWrapper.doSomethingElse();
        AOT likeNotWrapped = cotmWrapper;
        likeNotWrapped.doSomething();
    }

}


abstract class AOT {
    // Has few abstract methods and few default method implementation
    public abstract void doSomething();

    public void doAOTStuff() {
        // AOT stuff is doing
    }

}

abstract class AMOT extends AOT {
    // Has a new abstract method and few overridden methods
    public abstract void doSomethingElse();

    public void doSomething() {
        // AMOT stuff is doing
    }

}

class COTM extends AMOT {
    // Implementation class of the abstract hierarchy

    public void doSomethingElse() {
        doCOTMStuff();
    }

    public void doCOTMStuff() {
        // COTM stuff is doing
    }
}

abstract class AOTWrapper extends AOT implements AOTInterface {

    @Override
    public void doAOTStuff() {
        super.doAOTStuff();
    }

    // Has the default method implementation of AOT
}

abstract class AMOTWrapper extends AMOT implements AMOTInter {

       @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        super.doSomething();
    }

    // Has the default method implementation of AMOT
}

class COTMWrapper extends COTM implements COTMInter {

    @Override
    public void doSomethingElse() {
        super.doSomethingElse();
    }

    @Override
    public void doCOTMStuff() {
        super.doCOTMStuff();
    }
//     Implementation class of the abstract hierarchy
}


interface AOTInterface {

    void doSomething();

    void doAOTStuff();
}

interface AMOTInter extends AOTInterface {

    void doSomethingElse();

    void doSomething();
}

interface COTMInter extends AMOTInter {

    void doSomethingElse();

    void doCOTMStuff();
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: The COTM class will have to implement all abstract methods of the abstract hierarchy i.e. doSomething() of AOT and doSomethingElse() of AMOT. If our wrapper extends the implementation class, then integrators can't have any implementation without doSomethingElse()!

Comment: Not sure i got you well. If you wanted to say that AOTWrapper will have to override all COTM methods, its true, but you will chose what methods will be wrapped and which will throw exception. As I said, since you have no mutual interface I cant see any elegant solution. By the way the access will be  narrowed down if you use AOT aot = new AOTWrapper();

Comment: AOTWrapper should be similar to AOT i.e. the AOTWrapper shouldn't have doSomethingElse(). Integrators can extend either AOTWrapper or AMOTWrapper depending on the need

Comment: They will see the parent methods but they will not be able to use them. If you want to make it clean you can reject your wrappers inheritance and make this construction: `abstract class AOTWrapper extends AOT implements AOTInterface`  write needed interfaces and inherit them from on another `interface AMOTInter extends AOTInterface` and so on.